# Ionic checkbox anyone select value

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here is my template

```
<ion-list >
          <ion-item>
               <ion-label>This month</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox checked=true></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
               <ion-label>Previous month</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
               <ion-label>last 3 month</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
               <ion-label>This Year</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
               <ion-label>Previous Year</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
               <ion-label>All Time</ion-label>
               <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

I select any value ex This.month and same time select Previous month.and also checked two values.I need check only Previous month.

How can i do this.

can u help me...

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checkbox alert that saves to a variable the results of multiple selection.

In your html have a button calling your function

```
<button ion-button block (click)="selection()">Filter</button>
```

In your .TS handle the alert presenting and data.

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public alerts: AlertController){}

selection() {
    let a = this.alerts.create({
        title: 'My select',
        inputs: [
            { type: 'radio', label: 'This Month', value: 'This Month' },
            { type: 'radio', label: 'Previous Month', value: 'Previous Month' },
            { type: 'radio', label: 'Last 3 Months', value: 'Last 3 Months' },
            { type: 'radio', label: 'This Year', value: 'This Year' },
            { type: 'radio', label: 'Previous Year', value: 'Previous Year' },
            { type: 'radio', label: 'All Time', value: 'All Time' },
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Ok',
                handler: data => {
                    // DATA IS AN STRING ONLY, IF YOU SELECT 'ALL TIME' THEN DATA WILL BE 'ALL TIME'
                }
            }]
    })

    a.present();
}
```

If you need this on your screen not as a form of alert, check the official docs for [radio buttons](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/).

Hope this helps